# React-Bootstrap Full screen Modal Dialog

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I am currently attempting to make the Modal component included with react-bootstrap to appear full screen.

I can see from the documentation that the individual components of the Dialog (Modal, Header, Footer, Body) accept custom classes through "bsClass", however once rendered the height is being restricted by another div with the class "modal-content", but cannot see a way of passing a custom class to this.

Is it possible to do this, or is there another way of achieving the same effect without manually changing the class once the dialog has rendered?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it's documented on their website but you can only change the `base class` the `subcomponent` such as `Modal.header, Modal.footer` doesn't add `custom classes` so you may have to face some difficulties to do it with CSS code, here is my modal code,

```
     <Modal
      {...this.props}
      show={this.state.show}
      onHide={this.hideModal}
      dialogClassName="custom-modal"
      bsClass="my-modal"
    >
```

With below CSS code I was able to make the bootstrap code full screen

```
@media (min-width: 992px)
.my-modal-lg {
    width: auto;
}

@media (min-width: 768px)
.my-modal-dialog {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
 }

@media (min-width: 768px)
.my-modal-content {
    box-shadow: 0 5px 15px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    height: auto;
    min-height: 100%;
    border-radius: 0;
}
```

To get more control of your `modal` `data`, `form`, `text` i would suggest to have a look at the following GitHub `react-bootstrap-modal` repo

https://github.com/jquense/react-bootstrap-modal

and if you want to try anything except `bootstrap modal`, then you can also have a look at the `react-modal` by visiting below url,

https://github.com/reactjs/react-modal

Comment: Update for 2022: Modals can now be made full screen in React-Bootstrap by simply adding the fullscreen prop. Please see the documentation for more information: https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/modal/

Answer (score 3):

EDIT: Thanks to Aravind Reddy for pointing out that the fullscreen prop is only available in v5.

According to this documentation https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/modal/ you can include a `size` of `'sm' | 'lg' | 'xl'` as a prop for `Modal`. There is also a `fullscreen` property that accepts `'true' |'sm-down' | 'md-down' | 'lg-down' | 'xl-down' | 'xxl-down'`.

Example of using size

```
  const [smShow, setSmShow] = useState(false);
  const [lgShow, setLgShow] = useState(false);

  return (
    <>
      <Button onClick={() => setSmShow(true)}>Small modal</Button>{' '}
      <Button onClick={() => setLgShow(true)}>Large modal</Button>
      <Modal
        size="sm"
        show={smShow}
        onHide={() => setSmShow(false)}
        aria-labelledby="example-modal-sizes-title-sm"
      >
        <Modal.Header closeButton>
          <Modal.Title id="example-modal-sizes-title-sm">
            Small Modal
          </Modal.Title>
        </Modal.Header>
        <Modal.Body>...</Modal.Body>
      </Modal>
      <Modal
        size="lg"
        show={lgShow}
        onHide={() => setLgShow(false)}
        aria-labelledby="example-modal-sizes-title-lg"
      >
        <Modal.Header closeButton>
          <Modal.Title id="example-modal-sizes-title-lg">
            Large Modal
          </Modal.Title>
        </Modal.Header>
        <Modal.Body>...</Modal.Body>
      </Modal>
    </>
  );
}

render(<Example />);
```

And the example of fullscreen

```
  const values = [true, 'sm-down', 'md-down', 'lg-down', 'xl-down', 'xxl-down'];
  const [fullscreen, setFullscreen] = useState(true);
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);

  function handleShow(breakpoint) {
    setFullscreen(breakpoint);
    setShow(true);
  }

  return (
    <>
      {values.map((v, idx) => (
        <Button key={idx} className="me-2" onClick={() => handleShow(v)}>
          Full screen
          {typeof v === 'string' && `below ${v.split('-')[0]}`}
        </Button>
      ))}
      <Modal show={show} fullscreen={fullscreen} onHide={() => setShow(false)}>
        <Modal.Header closeButton>
          <Modal.Title>Modal</Modal.Title>
        </Modal.Header>
        <Modal.Body>Modal body content</Modal.Body>
      </Modal>
    </>
  );
}

render(<Example />);
```

Comment: Nice attempt copy pasting from the docs.  fullscreen prop only comes with v5

Comment: Yes these examples are copied from the docs which I also linked and stated according to this documentation.  I assumed they were on latest version.

Answer (score 2):

Try with this CSS code,

```
  .custom-modal{
     width: 100VW;
     height: 100VH;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the ideas from [ConAirCode](https://onaircode.com/modal-alert-dialog-component-for-react/) and the React-Bootstrap docs, this is what I did:

```
<Modal id="fullScreenModalId" show={show} onHide={handleClose} dialogClassName="fullscreen-modal" >
    <Modal.Header closeButton>
        <Modal.Title>Full Screen</Modal.Title>
    </Modal.Header>
    <Modal.Body>
         I'm full screen
    </Modal.Body>
    <Modal.Footer>
         <Button variant="secondary" onClick={handleClose}>
              Minimize Screen
         </Button>
         <Button variant="primary" onClick={handleSaveAll}>
              Save Changes
         </Button>
     </Modal.Footer>
</Modal>
```

With this for the css:

```
.fullscreen-modal.modal-dialog  {
    position: absolute;
    top: 40px;
    left: 40px;
    right: 40px;
    bottom: 40px;
    background-color: papayawhip;
}

.fullscreen-modal .modal-content {
    position: fixed;
    top: 50px;
    left: 50px;
    right: 50px;
    bottom: 50px;
    background-color: rebeccapurple;
 }
```

The css referencing is important to reference the proper elements. Pay particular attention to the where the spaces are. They are necessary to actually reference the proper element while also avoiding referencing all modals you may have. Also, I'm not sure how important the css is for the modal-dialog because the modal-content element overlaps it with these settings. Note: the state variables and methods should be self explanatory (I didn't include all the methods and state variables as they aren't important to the question).

Answer (score 0):

<Modal **fullscreen={true}**> To make the modal fullscreen, use the fullscreen prop [docs](https://react-bootstrap.netlify.app/components/modal/#fullscreen-modal)

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';
import Modal from 'react-bootstrap/Modal';

function Example() {
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);

  const handleClose = () => setShow(false);
  const handleShow = () => setShow(true);

  return (
    <>
      <Button variant="primary" onClick={handleShow}>
        Launch demo modal
      </Button>

      <Modal fullscreen={true} show={show} onHide={handleClose}>
        <Modal.Header closeButton>
          <Modal.Title>Modal heading</Modal.Title>
        </Modal.Header>
        <Modal.Body>Woohoo, you're reading this text in a modal!</Modal.Body>
        <Modal.Footer>
          <Button variant="secondary" onClick={handleClose}>
            Close
          </Button>
          <Button variant="primary" onClick={handleClose}>
            Save Changes
          </Button>
        </Modal.Footer>
      </Modal>
    </>

     );
  }
```